# what does the code bellow does in javascript explanation?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
function power(a,b){ 
  return b--?a*power(a,b):1;
}
```

I don't understand that line of code   b--?a*power(a,b):1 
 a function that returns the power of a number without using any math function like power(a,b) of a ** b

Comment: It uses recursion to multiply several times.

Comment: It does a recoursive multiplication.

Comment: This should really be written as `return b > 0 ? a * power(a, b - 1) : 1`

Comment: What part of that line exactly do you not understand? Do you understand the used operators? Have you done some debugging? Have you evaluated some example calls by hand?

Answer (score 1):

It'll be clearer if you move the `b--` to its own line. Assuming that `b` is a positive integer, the code is equivalent to:

```
function power(a,b){ 
  const bBeforeDecrement = b;
  b--;
  return bBeforeDecrement !== 0
    ? a * power(a,b)
    : 1;
}
```

`power` recursively calls itself, multiplying the ultimate return value by `a` each iteration, decrementing `b` and recursively calling itself until `b` reaches 0.

At the end, the return value is `a` multiplied by itself `b` times.

Like the comment notes, the reassignment of `b` makes things more confusing than it needs to be - it would make more sense to subtract 1 from `b` in the recursive call instead:

```
function power(a,b){ 
  return b > 0
    ? a * power(a, b - 1)
    : 1;
}
```